# How to breakspace in Appended String on Files?

Tags: android, file, file-io, spinner, android-spinner

OKay so I'm handling Files where I ask user Input and my program updates the Spinner with new selection.

Here's the codes for write:

```
public void writeOnFile(String string){
    try {
        FileOutputStream file = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_APPEND);
        file.write(string.getBytes());
        file.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and read:

```
public void readOnFile(){

    try {
        FileInputStream file = openFileInput(fileName);
        if(file!=null){
            InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(file);
            BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
            String course;
            while((course = buffreader.readLine()) != null){
                                         adapter.add(course);
                }

        }
        file.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and here's bit of my spinner's code:

```
courseSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.courseSpinner);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter <CharSequence> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    readOnFile();
    adapter.add("The Country Club");
    courseSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When I update the Spinner instead of seeing two selections which is "course 1" and "course" 2
I see one selection with the text "course 1course 2" :/

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are interpreting the strings as separated by newline, you need to write each of the strings to new line in the file.

Change your write code to:

```
public void writeOnFile(String string){
try {
    FileOutputStream file = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_APPEND);
    file.write(string.getBytes());
    file.write("\n".getBytes());
    file.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```